# JavaScript framework for drawing workflow diagrams

Tags: javascript, extjs, drawing, uml, relationship

Does anyone know about any JavaScript frameworks used for developing workflow-like diagrams?  I'm looking for ways to show relationships between objects and to be able to drag the objects around within the browser.  I'm looking for something similar to the functionality of Microsoft Visio.

Has anyone done anything similar with the Ext JS framework?  This is all I've seen out there so far.
http://kforner.github.com/extjs-dag-drawer/example.html

And I'd like to be able to drag components around like this.
http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

Comment: found another one ... http://www.yworks.com/products/yfileshtml/eap/demos/GraphViewerDemos/demo.yfiles.graph.simpleeditor/index.html

Comment: http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_practicalinfo_demos.html#html5

Comment: INCREDIBLE!!  http://www.yworks.com/products/yfilessilverlight/Demo.yFiles.Graph.Collapse.html

Comment: here's another: https://www.gliffy.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean like http://www.draw.io/?

This browser-based tool lets you draw UML style diagrams (and workflow diagrams) and then export / save as in your desired format.

Searching for UML tools will help you find others if this doesn't suit your needs.

For the JS library itself, the above uses http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html

Comment: I guess my question was a dup.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153334/are-there-any-javascript-graphics-libraries-that-support-visio-like-diagram-crea

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest [Graphiti](http://draw2d.org/graphiti/jsdoc/#!/example) which is based on RaphaelJS. In this case you have the power
of raphaelJS API and community and a better object/API handlin than in the graffle demo page.

Greetings

Comment: Sweet!  Did you develop this?  Is this based on the ExtJS framework?

Comment: The guy who wrote RaphaelJS built Sencha's (or extjs's) draw package. You can do the same stuff in both.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a javascript framework, take a look: http://jsplumbtoolkit.com

Comment: Quick question.. is there a way for someone to take a graph (where nodes have multiple parents) and create a diagram on the fly?  Example, suppose you had a table with two columns: parent_node and child_node.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use jsplumb still just watching for a later project. Must dig API friend... Sorry.